# Using jQuery each() w/ parameter-taking function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parameters, each

I have a bunch of divs of classname foo within a div of classname fooContainer (these foo divs have been dynamically added to fooContainer).

I have a function operateOnFoo(fooObjectToBeOperatedOn) that operates on a single foo div (that is passed into operateOnFoo as a parameter).

I would like to use the jQuery each() feature to run the operateOnFoo function on all/each of the divs of classname foo within fooContainer.  I have tried using calls like:

```
operateOnFoo( $("#fooContainter").each( ".foo" ) );
```

and

```
$("#fooContainter").each( operateOnFoo( foo ) );
```

and

```
$("#fooContainer").find(".foo").each( operateOnFoo( ".foo" ) );
```

but I just can't get it to work.  How do I proceed?

I'm a little new to web developing, teaching myself as I go along, so I apologize if this question is overly basic - but I couldn't seem to get it working using other similar Stack Exchange posts as I have been able to do with most of my other issues.

Thanks!

Comment: You want `$("#fooContainer .foo").each( operateOnFoo );`

Comment: @Bergi - `operateOnFoo` wants the element as the first argument which isn't how `.each()` calls its callback.

Comment: @jfriend00: Oh, right, I always forget that jQuery `each` is broken.

Comment: Is "fooContainer" an id value or a class name?

Comment: use $("#fooContainer .foo").toArray().map( operateOnFoo ); for such arity.

Answer (score 1):

The `.each()` callback is what it is and you can't change the number of arguments to it or the order in which they appear.  So, because your `operateOnFoo()` function wants different arguments, you can't have `.each()` call it directly as it is.  You can work around it though like this with a stub function that makes the arguments work like you want:

```
$("#fooContainer .foo").each(function(index, element) {
    operateOnFoo(element);
});
```

Also, the single selector `"#fooContainer .foo"` will select all items with `class="foo"` that are contained within the object with `id=fooContainer`.

---

If you can change `operateOnFoo()` to accept the exact two arguments that `.each()` uses (even if you ignore the first argument), so it was declared like this:

```
function operateOnFoo(index, element) {...}
```

then you would be able to just do:

```
$("#fooContainer .foo").each(operateOnFoo);
```

Answer (score 0):

`each` require a function call back ,so give it a function.

`$("#fooContainer").find(".foo").each( function(k, div){ operateOnFoo(div) } );`

Comment: You missed the part in the question where `operateOnFoo()` wants the element passed as the first argument to it.  As you have it, the `.each` index will be passed as the first argument to `operateOnFoo()`.

Comment: Arh, yes confused with angular which first argument is value. edited

Answer (score 0):

Considering `fooContainer` to be a class and not the ID of the container. You can use it like so:

```
$(".fooContainer .foo").each(function(index, element){
    operateOnFoo(element);
});
```

Comment: Why did you change `fooContainer` into a class when the OP specifies it as an id?

Comment: Who says `fooContainer` is an id? It is clearly mentioned in the question as "div of classname fooContainer"

Comment: The OP is using `"#fooContainter"` in three places which leads one to believe they are using an id..., but they don't show their HTML so it isn't 100% clear, I guess.

Comment: @jfriend00 maybe you are correct but as the OP said that he/she is new in web development, so I guessed that his syntax would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#fooContainer .foo").each(function(index, element){

     //Your code goes here...
     alert("Foo index: " + index + "\nContent: " + element);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$(".fooContainter .foo").each(function (i,  foo) { operateOnFoo( foo )}; );`

The `$(".fooContainter .foo")` will select all the elements with class `foo` under `fooContainer`

Comment: Where does that `foo` variable come from?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the index and element.